# Visible pencils marks when digitizing pencil retouched negatives

Tags: scanning, negative-film, retouching

I have several old medium format portrait negatives that were retouched manually by a master photographer back in the day.

When exposed on a photographic paper, they looked amazing.

However, now when I'm trying to digitize them with a DSLR, all the retouching is extremely visible:

[image]

Any idea or tricks how to get rid of or at least minimize it? I tried "scanning" both sides, but on the emulsion side, the pencil is visible even more and the lines are much sharper.

Retouching it manually looks like a lot of work as on some areas (shadows under the eyes for example), retouching was even heavier.

I was thinking about trying to do a separate overexposed scan in the hopes that only the retouching marks will remain, but even in that case it would be very difficult to align it with the normally exposed one.

Comment: If you look at the negatives with a grazing light, are there any visible creases with the pencil marks?

Comment: What source of light are you shining through the negatives when you shoot them?

Comment: @xenoid with a grazing light they are not visible anymore

Comment: @LightBender it's a LED light panel for slide/negative viewing

Comment: Are the marks equally visible in all channels? Might be related to the limited sensitivity of black and white paper

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will remove pencil, but my "go to" product for removing almost anything from a slide or negative is [PEC-12](https://photosol.com/products/pec-12/) (Photographic Emulsion Cleaner). It will even remove Sharpie™ permanent marker! It also deals with mould that has not eaten into the emulsion.

If you often deal with slides or negatives, it's worth keeping a bottle around!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ordered some PEC-12 - it will come in handy anyway - but unfortunately it does not remove pencil marks.